# Exception while adding second DbContext in .net 5 Code First Approach

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I already have added first migration with Postgres which is working. Now want to add second migration with .net InMemory database. But getting following exception while executing `dotnet ef migrations add InMemoryMigrationContext --context CacheDbContext`:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrator'. This is often because no database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

Here are my code parts: (lines are omited for simplicity)

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o => o.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDbContext<CacheDbContext>(o => o.UseInMemoryDatabase("CachedShortUrl"));

    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(ICachedDbRepository<>), typeof(CachedDbRepository<>));
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs:**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options){}
    public DbSet<ShortUrl> ShortUrls { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ShortUrl>().HasData(new ShortUrl[]{
            new ShortUrl{ URL="https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/11/25/getting-started-with-entity-framework-core-5/", ShortedURL="https://blog.jetbrains.com/12345", IsExpired=false }
        });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**CacheDbContext.cs:**

```
public class CacheDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CacheDbContext(DbContextOptions<CacheDbContext> options) : base(options){}
    public DbSet<CachedShortUrl> CachedShortUrls {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

**IRepository.cs:** `public interface IRepository<T> where T : Entity`

**Repository.cs:**

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _entities;
}
```

**ICachedDbRepository.cs:** `public interface ICachedDbRepository<T> where T : Entity`

**CacheDbRepository.cs:**

```
public class CachedDbRepository<T> : ICachedDbRepository<T> where T : Entity
{
    private readonly CacheDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _entities;
}
```